# Doctrine 2.1 - Removing from collection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to remove comments from a parent entity, I remember doing this on my last website but now it's not working..

My entity - users

```
namespace Application\Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM,
    Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Loan
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string $username
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", mappedBy="author", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $comments;

    public function getComments(){

          return $this->comments;              

    }
```

and my comments table:

```
    namespace Application\Entities;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM,
        Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Loan
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="comments")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Comments{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var integer $user_id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=15, nullable=false)
     */
    private $user_id

    /**
     * @var Loan
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="comments",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $author;
```

This is fine, it works and I get all collections called comments in the users repository..

Now, I usually do this when I need to delete:

```
$commentToDelete = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Comments')->findOneById(375);
$userResults = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Users')->findOneById(23);
$userResults->getComments()->removeElement($commentToDelete);
$this->em->flush();
```

Nothing deletes, neither it throws an exception to tell me it hasn't.

I doctrine flushed it too, checked the db, and it's still there..

**UPDATE:**
Straight after I removeElement, I looped through the user id = 23 dataset, and the comment data for id375 is not there...  so it removed it from the collection but not from the DB, and I thought `$em->flush()` is supposed to do this?

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to tell the entitymanager to persist $userResults before you flush?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use

```
$em->remove($commentToDelete);
$em->flush();
```

Because the mapping is held in the comment you need to remove this entity to remove the reference before you flush which will save the state to the db.

Comment: But this will delete the comment entirely from the DB (which is exactly what the OP need). But how you remove just the association between two entities?

Comment: hey, thanks,  but do i still need to unset this comment from the collection too? as well as a em->remove?

Comment: If you just want to remove the association, just unset the reference in the comment and flush 'unset($commentToDelete->author); $em->flush();'. If you want to delete the comment, you don't need to unset before you remove then flush. Remember, there is no data stored in the Users table about the comments. Doctrine just gives you access to the comments in the User model via the mapping.

Comment: I've just thought. Might there be a problem with your flush when you remove the element because of a constraint in the database that the author(user_id) field can't be empty? Sorry I don't deal with the ORM much and was thinking in ODM terms.